# Is listening on the scroll event always bad for performance?

Tags: javascript

I know that listening for the scroll event is to be avoided, if possible. But sometimes it's hard to avoid.

I want to make an element sticky, by toggling position: fixed on it as I scroll past. Can't use position:sticky, separate discussion.

Here's the simplified version of what I want to do: if I'm scrolled farther than 200px, I want to apply the class.

I know I'm running this if (> 200){...} check every time I scroll, but will this check actually affect performance?  I tried debouncing it but even at 50ms, I can scroll past the element and have jank as it becomes sticky.

Even if the 50ms debouncing worked visually, I'm still running this function every 50ms....which is probably also bad.

Any thoughts?

```
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', () => {
    if ( 200 > window.pageYOffset ) {
        document.body.classList.remove( 'search-filters-sticky' );
    } else {
        document.body.classList.add( 'search-filters-sticky' );
    }
} );
```

Comment: You are not doing any dom lookups, so this is relatively "not bad".  It's just possibly trying to remove a class that is already not there, or add a class that is already there, over and over

Comment: Only thing I could see is you use a boolean to say if it was added or removed yet so you are not doing the dom lookup when nothing really changed.

Comment: Thought about the boolean, but I still need to be listening for scrolling to know how to set the boolean (I think?)

Comment: The boolean would flip any time you do the add or remove.  And there would be an additional if around those to not do the remove/add if it's already flipped

Comment: There is no way to avoid listening to scrolling, but you can limit the calls inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is generally bad for performance. Look up blog post here of how Twitter implements it :
https://johnresig.com/blog/learning-from-twitter/